# Concatenate Import Expression in SQL

Tags: sql, excel, export, concatenation

> I have the following query:

```
    select @Box=Box,@Code=Code,@Validity=Validity,@Type=[Type]
    FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
   'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Barcodes.xlsx;HDR=YES',
   'SELECT Box,Code,Validity,[Type ] FROM [sheet1$]')
    where Code <> ''
```

> I am trying to Concatenate : 'C:\Barcodes.xlsx' , i want to put  a value "@Path" to be given
>   by the use dynamically , i tried so far '+' '%' and nothing worked , what should i do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean but at a guess?

```
select 
    @Box=Box,@Code=Code,@Validity=Validity,@Type=[Type]
FROM 
  OPENROWSET(
   'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
   'Excel 12.0;Database=' + @path + ';HDR=YES',
   'SELECT Box,Code,Validity,[Type ] FROM [sheet1$]')
where 
  Code <> ''
```

Comment: tell us what's in the variables in your question

Comment: @Box=Box,@Code=Code,@Validity=Validity,@Type=[Type] are variable taken from the excel file itself taken from a cursor , but don't mind that , @Path should be a nvarchar(50) that has a value like (i.e) `**C:\Excel.xslx**`

Comment: i tried your method and it says  : `Incorrect syntax near '+' `